# How to use local classes with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, local-class

GCC doesn't seem to approve of instanciating templates with local classes:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T);

void g()
{
    struct s {};

    f(s()); // error: no matching function for call to 'f(g()::s)'
}
```

VC doesn't complain.

How should it be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++03 it can't be done, C++0x will [lift](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#local-types) that restriction though.

C++03, *§14.3.1/2*:

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.