# Template instantiation refused with function-local classes

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use local classes with templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172909/how-to-use-local-classes-with-templates)

g++ 4.4 is refusing to compile a call to a template function taking a function-local class as a template parameter.  Like so:

```
// Given this:
template <typename C>
int f(const C& c) {
  return c.g();
}

// This compiles fine:
struct C1 {
    int g() const { return 42; }
};

int h1() {
    return f(C1());
}

// But this doesn't:
int h2() {
    struct C2 {
        int g() const { return 42; }
    };
    return f(C2()); // error: no matching function for call to "f(h2()::C2)"
}

// Nor does this:
int h3() {
    struct C3 {
        int g() const { return 42; }
    };
    return f<C3>(C3()); // same error
}
```

What gives?  How do I make this work?  (In the real program from which this is pruned, "h" is a member function, and "C" has to be a nested class so that it's implicitly a friend of the class of which "h" is a member.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++0x will remove this undesirable restriction.

For now, you can make C *i* a proper nested class (inside of `h`'s class, not inside of `h`).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. It's unfortunate, because "C" is only used in that one place, but at least I don't have to make things public that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

local class may not be template parameter.

[C++ can local class reference be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662843/c-can-local-class-reference-be-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: Chapter and verse, please?  Or link to further explication?

Comment: @Zac was looking for link, updated information

Comment: @Zac might solve problem for you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Template parameters must have extern linkage.